# does `getvs` in confd work with yaml list?

Tags: templates, confd

I have set a yml file as confd backend. I have a yaml list to process something as below.

```
otherargs:
- "-Xmx256m"
- "-Xmn128m"
```

and trying to read the value from the list below.  As this is a list I am using getvs to get all values in string[] and join those with ',' .  Referring [join](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd/blob/master/docs/templates.md#join).

```
values : [ {{$args := getvs "/otherargs"}}
                 {{join $args ","}}]
```

Output I received is as below

```
values : []
```

Here I am not getting the values from the yaml list via `getvs` .
As it is a list, the data should be collected via `getvs` but why I am receiving empty string I am not even getting single value here. so Does `getvs` work with yaml list? If yest then what am I missing here?

I also tried `range` functionality to get values received via `getvs` as below referring [getvs](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd/blob/master/docs/templates.md#getvs)

```
values :  [{{range getvs "/otherargs"}}
                  {{.}},
                  {{end}}]
```

but received same empty array as result. :(

any help would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from [here](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd/pull/397#issuecomment-188616839) I was trying to use `getvs` but the solution to this issue was `ls` command. Now I am able to populate this list from yml with below code.

```
 values :  [{{ $otherargs := ls "/otherargs" }}
             "{{join $otherargs "\",\""}}"]
```

so final result, I received as below

```
 values : ["-Xmx256m", "-Xmn128m"]
```